# Save relationships between many existing records and one new record

Tags: cakephp, save, has-and-belongs-to-many

Using CakePHP, I have events and people. I want to assign many existing people to an event I'm creating when I save that new event. I'm selecting the people using checkboxes.

My data looks like:

```
data[Event][name]:Test 4
data[Event][event_type_id]:1
data[EventPerson][person_id]:
data[EventPerson][person_id][]:65
data[EventPerson][person_id][]:72
data[EventPerson][person_id][]:67
```

I have `Event` and `Person` models, set with HABTM relationships to each other, as well as an `events_people` table and model, and those are properly set up.

I've tried `$this->Event->saveAssociated` and `$this->Event->saveAll`. Each will save the event record with the correct information, neither saves the relationship to the people.

The people will *always* exist already when the event is saved. I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I've been wracking my brain for hours with no change in results.

**Tried**

Controller

```
$this->Event->create();
    if ($this->Event->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The event has been saved'));
        return $this->redirect...
    }
$people= $this->FestivalPerson->find('all', 
    array(
        "Person.name",
        "conditions" => array(
            "festival_id" => $this->request->query["festival_id"]
        ), 
        "order" => "Person.name ASC"
    )
);
$this->set("eventPeople", Set::combine($people, '{n}.Person.id', '{n}.Person.name'));
```

View:

```
echo $this->Form->input('EventPerson', array('multiple' => 'checkbox'));
```

Data:

```
data[Event][EventPerson]:
data[Event][EventPerson][]:50
data[Event][EventPerson][]:65
data[Event][EventPerson][]:71
```

That looks like it matches the structure per examples and should save properly, but my `events_people` tables is still empty. No errors coming out of PHP/MySQL at all either.

Comment: @AD7six added more information. This is the relevant part of the controller/view, which grabs the person list based on a passed festival id (I'm listing people related with a festival when creating an event at that festival. Only people related to the festival will be at the event.)

Comment: That's not the right form/data structure for trying to save a HABTM relationship - hence it doesn't work.

Comment: @AD7six I'm not able to try out J.D.'s answer at the moment, but I believe you are both correct about the data structure being wrong. Is there an proper way to create the form element that I'm missing? I'd rather not manipulate the data manually.

Comment: see [the docs (near the end of that section)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm) or e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5702867/761202), or use bake to generate a working view and edit it. Basically you want `echo $this->Form->input('EventPerson')` - feel free to make this comment into an answer and accept it once you've got a solution.

Comment: @AD7six Thanks, that sounds promising. Won't be able to get at my code for a while. I know I've seen you answer on other questions of mine in the past, I probably ought to just put you on my payroll.

Comment: @AD7six Still no success: event saves, events_people table is empty. Updated with new code ^

Comment: @AD7six also tried with `$this->Form->input('Person'...)`

Comment: It should be `$this->Form->input('HABTMAssociationName')` - It's not clear if that is or is not the case. The resultant data format would be `$data['Person']['Person'][id, id, id]` If you don't get that data format, the _form input_ is wrong. You can force/hint it using `$this->Form->input('Person.Person')`. Please use the irc channel for interactive help.

Comment: @AD7six those changes (along with a small model issue that may or may not have been related, not entire certain) got it working, thanks! 2 things: What's "irc channel" and how do I give you credit for the answer?

Comment: The irc channel is [one of the places to get help](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/where-to-get-help.html#the-irc-channel), [irc](https://www.google.com/search?q=what's+irc) is simply a chat room. e.g. [this is the log for CakePHP's main chat room](http://irc.cakephp.org/). Just write up what you did and what changede as an answer and accept it - that's credit enough =).

Answer (score 1):

Form your data like this

```
data[Event][name]:Test 4
data[Event][event_type_id]:1
data[EventPerson][0][person_id]:
data[EventPerson][1][person_id][]:65
data[EventPerson][2][person_id][]:72
data[EventPerson][2][person_id][]:67
```

or follow this article: http://patisserie.keensoftware.com/en/pages/how-to-save-habtm-data-in-cakephp

It explains how to write custom code for data arrays in cakePhp, I belive there is a similar example there