# HABTM SaveAssociated is performing a SELECT instead UPDATE in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

When performin the following SaveAll:

```
$this->loadModel('Foo');

    $my_data = array(   
        'Foo'=> array('id' => 1),
        'Bar' => array()
        );
    $my_values = array(1, 2, 3);
    foreach ($my_values as $key => $value) {
                array_push($my_data['Bar'], array(
                    'id' => $value,
                    )
                );
            }
    $this->Foo->saveAll($data, array('deep' => true));
```

The [foo_has_bar] table wasn't updated.

When checking the queries i've found just a SELECT:

```
BEGIN;  
UPDATE my_db.foo SET id = 1 WHERE my_db.foo.id = 1;
SELECT foo_has_bar.bar_id FROM my_db.foo_has_bar AS foo_has_bar WHERE foo_has_bar.foo_id = 1;
COMMIT;
```

My Model are the following:

FOO MODEL:

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Bar' => array(
            'className' => 'Bar',
            'joinTable' => 'foo_has_bar',
            'foreignKey' => 'foo_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'bar_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'deleteQuery' => '',
            'insertQuery' => ''
        )
    );
```

The `my_data` generated array are the folowing: `{"Foo":{"id":1},"Bar":[{"id":1},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"}]`

if I supress the Multisave, and generate an array like this: `{"Foo":{"id":1},"Bar":{"id":"3"}` every thing works fine.

Why when pushing multiple `bar` it doesn't save?

Comment: Please check the existing questions regarding saving HABTM. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5702867/1392379 | http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcakephp%5D+save+habtm

Comment: you can not save data in bar table using habtm. It will save data in foo table and in foo_has_bar table if there will be records in bar table for id's you supplied. Check http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm